# Tkinter Radiobutton not working in a program with more than one tk window

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, mysql-connector-python

Tkinter radiobutton using StringVar (for gender selection purpose in a python-mysql connectivity project) works fine in a small pgm *( with only one tk window)*. Same set of buttons (with same variable and code) does not work when in "a larger pgm with **more than one tk window"**. It always returns an empty value. Why is this?

Comment: @Module_art: It's not a bug per se. It's simply how tkinter is designed to work.

Comment: If you need to create more than one window, it is recommended that you use `Toplevel` rather than `Tk` for the second and subsequent windows. Is there a reason why you think you need to have more than once instance of `Tk`?